# Compare dictionaries when elements are not equal

Tags: ansible

I have those 2 dictionaries that I would like to compare.
Note that the keys name are always the same but the 2 dictionaries don't always have the same numbers of elements.

It can happen that the 2 dictionaries have the same number of elements but it will not always be the case

```yaml
  dictionary_1:
    apple: 4
    banana: 5
    orange: 6
```

```yaml
  dictionary_2:
    apple: 5
    banana: 5
```

What I want to do it's to fail when one value in dictionary_2 is higher than the value in dictionary_1 for the same key, but not fail if value in dictionary_2 is lower than the value in dictionary_1 for the same key.

Also, not fail if dictionary_1 have more elements than dictionary_2.

In this example, apple's value is equal to 5 in dictionary_2 and equal to 4 in dictionary_1, so, i want that it's says that the value for apple in dictionary_1 is higher than the value in dictionary_2.

What I have tried, it works only if the values are equals and the 2 dictionaries have the same numbers of elements.

```yaml
- name: Check dictionaries
  assert:
    that: dictionary_2 == dictionary_1
    fail_msg: "Error"
    success_msg: " Success"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mix in some jinja and do something like that.
This way, it will only do the comparison on existing keys

```
    - name: Compare dictionaries
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} in dict1 is {{ 'higher' if item.value > dict2[item.key] else 'lower' if item.value < dict2[item.key] else 'equal' }} than in dict2"
      loop: "{{ dict1 | dict2items }}"
      when: item.key in dict2.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the dictionaries

```yaml
  d1:
    apple: 4
    banana: 5
    orange: 6

  d2:
    apple: 5
    banana: 5
```

---

Get the values

```yaml
  vals: "{{ d2.values()|zip(d2.keys()|
                            map('extract', d1)) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  vals:
  - - 5
    - 4
  - - 5
    - 5
```

Create a list of dictionaries

```yaml
  l12: "{{ vals|map('zip', ['d2', 'd1'])|
                map('map', 'reverse')|
                map('community.general.dict') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l12:
  - d1: 4
    d2: 5
  - d1: 5
    d2: 5
```

Compare the values

```yaml
  comp: "{{ l12|json_query('[?d2>d1]') }}"
```

gives the list with items where value(s) from *d2* are greater compared to *d1*

```yaml
  comp:
  - d1: 4
    d2: 5
```

Putting it all together gives the same result

```yaml
  result: "{{ d2.values()|
              zip(d2.keys()|map('extract', d1))|
              map('zip', ['d2', 'd1'])|
              map('map', 'reverse')|
              map('community.general.dict')|
              json_query('[?d2>d1]') }}"
```

Test the length of the list *result*

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: result|length == 0
        fail_msg: Item(s) in d2 are greater than in d1
```

```yaml
TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: result|length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Item(s) in d2 are greater than in d1
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    d1:
      apple: 4
      banana: 5
      orange: 6

    d2:
      apple: 5
      banana: 5

    # Fail when a value in d2 is greater than in d1

    vals: "{{ d2.values()|zip(d2.keys()|
                              map('extract', d1)) }}"
    l12: "{{ vals|map('zip', ['d2', 'd1'])|
                  map('map', 'reverse')|
                  map('community.general.dict') }}"
    comp: "{{ l12|json_query('[?d2>d1]') }}"

    result: "{{ d2.values()|
                zip(d2.keys()|map('extract', d1))|
                map('zip', ['d2', 'd1'])|
                map('map', 'reverse')|
                map('community.general.dict')|
                json_query('[?d2>d1]') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: vals
    - debug:
        var: l12
    - debug:
        var: comp
    - debug:
        var: result

    - assert:
        that: result|length == 0
        fail_msg: Item(s) in d2 are greater than in d1
```

You can add the attribute *key* to the dictionaries and create a list of failed keys

```yaml
    result: "{{ d2.values()|
                zip(d2.keys()|map('extract', d1))|
                zip(d2.keys())|map('flatten')|
                map('zip', ['d2', 'd1', 'key'])|
                map('map', 'reverse')|
                map('community.general.dict')|
                json_query('[?d2>d1]') }}"
    failed_keys: "{{ result|map(attribute='key')|join(',') }}"
```

Then, use it in the module *assert*

```yaml
    - assert:
        that: result|length == 0
        fail_msg: Item(s) {{ failed_keys }} in d2 are greater than in d1
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: result|length == 0
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Item(s) apple in d2 are greater than in d1
```

Answer (score 0):

It works like this for me either:

```yaml
- name: Check value
  assert:
    that:
    - dictionary_1[item] is defined
    - dictionary_2[item] < dictionary_1[item]
    fail_msg: " {{ item }} exceeds the defined value "
    success_msg: " {{ item }}  match value"
  with_items: "{{ dictionary_1.keys() | list }}"
```

Comment: In the loop, it will fail on the first negative item. Declare the variables if you want to list all failed keys. You're welcome!